# Using SQLite to record sensor data

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new in Android. I am working on magnetic sensor in android phone. I am able to access the magnetic sensor and record the sensor data into the .csv file. But i want to record it in SQLite. The problem is that the magnetic sensor data can be obtained in onSensorChanged method in main activity and i dont know how to prepare insert class in SQLite which can obtain the data from the main activity. I have pasted the code for getting data and DBHelper class.

Any help will be useful . thank you in advance.

```js
// For accessing and displaying magnetic data

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    Sensor magnetometer;
    SensorManager sm;
    TextView magnetismx;
    TextView magnetismy;
    TextView magnetismz;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    public float a;
    public float b;
    public float c;
    
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
         sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        magnetismx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.magnetismx);
        magnetismy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.magnetismy);
        magnetismz = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.magnetismz);

        magnetometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(magnetometer.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        if (magnetometer == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Magnetometer not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        
        @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        a = event.values[0];
        b = event.values[1];
        c = event.values[2];

        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

            magnetismx.setText(Float.toString(event.values[0]));
            magnetismy.setText(Float.toString(event.values[1]));
            magnetismz.setText(Float.toString(event.values[2]));
        }
         @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

}




// my dbHelper class 

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final String DB_NAME = "Mag_Positioning.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    private static final String COLXAXIS = "X-AXIS";
    private static final String TABLENAME = "MAP_COORDINATES";
    private static final String COLYAXIS = "Y-AXIS";
    private static final String COLZAXIS = "Z-AXIS";

    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLENAME + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
                COLXAXIS + " INTEGER, " +
                COLYAXIS + " INTEGER, " +
                COLZAXIS + " INTEGER )";
        db.execSQL(createTable);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLENAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void insert(Integer x, Integer y, Integer z, SQLiteDatabase db ) {

        ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
        contentvalues.put("X-AXIS", x);
        contentvalues.put("Y-AXIS", y);
        contentvalues.put("Z-AXIS", z);
        db.insert("MAP_COORDINATES", null, contentvalues);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change your DB class as singleton like this, and change the data type Integer to **REAL** because you are going to store float value,

Note: "-" is not valid in sqlite name so I changed to "_", ex in X-AXIS I converted to X_AXIS.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "Mag_Positioning.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    private static final String COLXAXIS = "X_AXIS";
    private static final String TABLENAME = "MAP_COORDINATES";
    private static final String COLYAXIS = "Y_AXIS";
    private static final String COLZAXIS = "Z_AXIS";

    private static DBHelper mInstance;

    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public static DBHelper getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            synchronized (DBHelper.class) {
                if (mInstance == null) {
                    mInstance = new DBHelper(BaseApp.getApp());
                }
            }
        }

        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLENAME + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
                COLXAXIS + " REAL, " +
                COLYAXIS + " REAL, " +
                COLZAXIS + " REAL )";
        db.execSQL(createTable);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLENAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insert(float x, float y, float z) {

        ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
        contentvalues.put("X-AXIS", x);
        contentvalues.put("Y-AXIS", y);
        contentvalues.put("Z-AXIS", z);
        getWritableDatabase().insert("MAP_COORDINATES", null, contentvalues);
    }
}
```

If you already had BaseApplication class just ignore the below code

```
public class BaseApp extends Application {

    private static BaseApp mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static Application getApp() {
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

check you added your base class in mainfest file or not,

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".BaseApp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

After getting sensor data you can call like this,

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    a = event.values[0];
    b = event.values[1];
    c = event.values[2];

    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

        DBHelper.getInstance().insert(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error while running the program. The program stopped unexpectedly. The error are 1) SQLiteLog: near "-" : syntax error and 2) Sensor Manager : Exception dispatching input event. How can i solve it?

Comment: "-" in table column name is not valid, I updated my answer have a look.

Comment: Thanks its working. Will it be upgraded with new values automatically? And to access the database what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when working with a database helperclass you want to only have one instance of the object.
This can be realized like this:

**DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
....

    private static DBHelper instance;

    public static DBHelper getInstance (Context context) {
        if (instance == null)
            instace = new DBHelper (context);
        return instance;
     }

    private DBHelper (Context context) // Notice the private constructor 
        ....
    }

    ....
}
```

Now the helper can be accessed with `DBHelper.getInstance (this)` from your Activity

Note: This is called a singleton pattern